# Wi-Fi Direct in Windows 10 (Desktop)

Tags: windows, wifi-direct

I have recently started to have a deeper look into Wi-Fi Direct under Windows 10 (desktop version) and had a look into the API descriptions
from Microsoft => https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn457945(v=vs.85).aspx

One of the described methods there (WFDStartOpenSession) states that a previous pairing through the "Windows Pairing experience" (WPS ?) is required.
So i started to play a little bit with the pairing stuff by using a Windows 10 (Build 1607, Desktop) together with an Android-based smartphone (version 6.0.1) and
made the following observations:

- When i initiate the connection from my PC to the phone, it "basically" works i.e. the pairing dialog shows up on the phone's display and i can connect to it.
  Although it works, it's not really stable in my opinion - on my side it works 1 out of 3 times.
- After ~ 30 seconds, Windows disconnects from the phone (in the "Devices and printers" view) while the phone itself stays connected a little longer (then it also disconnects).
- When i initiate the connection from my phone to the Windows PC, nothing happens - no message box, no pop-up window :-(

Has anybody else seen this or similiar behavior ?

I tried it with 2 different USB adapters, one with a RTL8723BU chipset from Realtek and the other one with a RT5572 chipset from Mediatek Ralink - both show
exactly the same behavior.

In addition, i noticed that the "Realtek Wireless Lan Utility" to control and configure the USB adapter is not working anymore in Windows 10 (1607) when switching
from client to Access Point mode. I think it's somehow related to ICS, missing hosted network support ... don't know yet.
However, actually you don't need the tool from Realtek as you can for example use the mobile hotspot feature of Windows 10 to share your internet connection with your devices.

But without the Realtek tool i have not found any possibility to switch WiFi channels - does anybody have the same problem ? is there are solution available for that ?

Thanks

Comment: Dude, we're in 2023 and the same thing is happening to me (referring to the 3 bullet points you written), have you figured out why that happens?